# CRUD with Lithium & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, frameworks, lithium

I just started to play with the PHP framework lithium (v 0.10).
I followed [the quick start manual](http://lithify.me/docs/manual/quickstart) which uses MongoDB as database.
To learn a bit more about lithium, I wanted to switch the DBMS from MonogoDB to MySQL.

The problem I'm having that when I open `/posts/` in the browser lithium only shows a blank page with no error messages. Also, when I go to `/posts/add/`, the correct form is displayed, but after submitting the data (which is correctly written to the DB), lithium also just displays a blank page. What's going wrong?

Also, after reading the lithium docs on models in lithium, I'm still not quite sure what logic (in this case) belongs to the model.

`UPDATE 1:`

I looks like it there is a problem with the APC caching. After installing APC and renaming the folder containing the lithium, the application worked without an error. When leaving the name of the folder containing lithium unchanged, I got an cache error:

```
Warning: include(/var/www/web/frameworks/lithium/app/resources/tmp/cache/templates/template_views_layouts_default.html_886_1308416958_798.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/web/frameworks/lithium/libraries/lithium/template/view/adapter/File.php on line 111

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '/var/www/web/frameworks/lithium/app/resources/tmp/cache/templates/template_views_layouts_default.html_886_1308416958_798.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/web/frameworks/lithium/libraries/lithium/template/view/adapter/File.php on line 111
```

`END UPDATE 1`

I manually set a up a MySQL table `posts` with the rows `id`, `title` and `body`.

My `Posts.php` model in `/app/models`:

```
<?php
namespace app\models;

class Posts extends \lithium\data\Model {

}
?>
```

My `PostsController.php` controller in `/app/controllers`:

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use app\models\Posts;

class PostsController extends \lithium\action\Controller {


    public function index() {
        $posts = Posts::all();
        return compact('posts');
        var_dump($posts);
    }

    public function add() {
        if($this->request->data) {
            $post = Posts::create($this->request->data);
            $success = $post->save();
        }
        return compact('success');
    }
}
?>
```

And finally my views `index.html.php` in `/app/views/posts/`:

```
<?php foreach($posts as $post): ?>
<article>
    <h1><?=$post->title ?></h1>
    <p><?=$post->body ?></p>
</article>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And also `add.html.php` in `/app/views/posts/`:

```
<?=$this->form->create(); ?>
    <?=$this->form->field('title');?>
    <?=$this->form->field('body', array('type' => 'textarea'));?>
    <?=$this->form->submit('Add Post'); ?>
<?=$this->form->end(); ?>

<?php if ($success): ?>
    <p>Post Successfully Saved</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: what errors to you get or do not get at all, try to var_dump($posts) ?

Comment: @jurka: Not any at all. Chrome just shows an error page with `Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection. No Data was sent by the server.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of tips ...

1) Are you sure Lithium is running correctly in general? I'm confused as to what your actual question / problem is.

2) There is no need to make the change to your PostsController, `Posts::all();` is just shorthand for `Posts::find('all');`

3) You may need to change your Model for Posts, Lithium (with MySQL) will expect an **id** column in your table to use as a key, if you don't have a coloum named **id** you might need to add one to your model.

For example, if you have a table with columns like **postid**, **title**, **body**, **date** ... add this to your model

```
<?php
 namespace app\models;

 class Posts extends \lithium\data\Model { 
   public $_meta = array('key' => 'postid');        
 }

?>
```

Note the 'key' => 'postid' that will let lithium know to use **postid** as the key for the table instead of looking for **id**

4) Here's how to actually construct a MySQL query in your controller ...

```
public function locations($companyid,$state=null) {

 /* removes null or false values with array_filter() */
 $conditions = array_filter(array('companyid' => $companyid, 'state' => $state));

 /* pass $conditions array to the Locations model, find all, order by city */
 $locations = Locations::find('all', array( 
       'conditions' => $conditions,
       'order' => array('city' => 'ASC')
 ));

 return compact('locations');

}
```

Check out the Lithium Manual for more help: http://li3.me/docs/manual

**Models**

http://li3.me/docs/manual/working-with-data/using-models.md

**Controllers**

http://li3.me/docs/manual/handling-http-requests/controllers.md

**Views**

http://li3.me/docs/manual/handling-http-requests/views.md

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! I read the documentation for Models, Controller & Views and also updated my Question accordingly. I'm still not quite sure what is going wrong.

Comment: Could it be some kind of cache problem? Because I'm having the feeling that lithium isn't getting the changes I make to a file right away.

Comment: First thing I'd do is use .10 instead of the older 0.9.9 ... just about everything is setup the same (you can just copy your controller/models/views over) but it's much newer code. http://sourceforge.net/projects/li3/files/lithium-0_10/

Comment: I updated lithium to 0.10 an also updated my question accordingly (see the update section of the answer). The problem is solved, it looks like the fact that APC was not installed caused the problem.